# Remove jquery from webpack bundle

Tags: jquery, webpack

How can I remove jquery from a webpack bundle? The lib is being pulled by npm packages like vue-owl-carousel, becouse it has in its own dependencies. I don't want jquery to stay in my bundle. It is already included by default in CMS i'm working with. So how can I get rid of it?

Comment: In my case I have copied vue-owl-carousel locally and imported it in my components. But still don't know how to erase jquery with webpack